# Print list of files in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create simple GUI based on `JFrame` which allows the user after click on some `JButton` to show all .txt files in particular directory and print this "list" of file names into some `JTextField` in that `JFrame`. I'm new in the field of Java programming so could you help me, please.

```
package inputOutputProgram;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ProjectGUI extends JFrame {

JLabel label;
static JTextField tf;
JButton button;

public ProjectGUI() {       
    tf = new JTextField(10);
    add(tf);

}

void showFiles() {
      String path = "C:\\Users\\data"; 

      String files;
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
      {

       if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
       {
       files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
           if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
           {
              System.out.println(files);
            }
         }
      }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     ProjectGUI print = new ProjectGUI();

     print.showFiles();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having? your question is not clear.

Comment: This prints the results only into console, but I need to create some JTextField with the .txt files names.

Comment: *"print this "list" of file names into some JTextField"*  (shudder) Use a `JList`, or a `JTable` or `JTree`..  See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) which uses the last two.

Comment: `tf.setText()` to set the text

Comment: Use a JTextArea rather than JTextField. Call tf.append(files+"\n") after System.out

Comment: Code-formatted class names in the problem description. Removed the unnecessary "many thanks" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `JTextArea` instead of `JTextField` for printing in new lines.
2. Instead of `System.out.println` use `setText` of `JTextArea`
3. To make JFrame visible call `setVisible(true)` and `setSize(400,400)`

package inputOutputProgram;

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class ProjectGUI extends JFrame {

JLabel label;
static JTextArea tf;
JButton button;

public ProjectGUI() {


    tf = new JTextArea();
    add(tf);

    // set visible JFrame with some size (400x400)
    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true);

}

void showFiles() {
      String path = "C:\\Users\\data"; 

      String files;
      String fileNames = "";
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
      {

       if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
       {
       files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
           if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
           {
              fileNames += "\n" + files;
            }
        }
      }
      tf.setText( fileNames );
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {

     ProjectGUI print = new ProjectGUI();

     print.showFiles();

    }
}
```